# Proof verification $F_n(x) = n\left(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}\right)$. Does it converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$F_n(x) = n\left(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}\right)$$
Find the radius of convergence and conclude if the convergence is uniform.

I changed $F_n(x)$ to be $$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x}}$$ 
from here its easy so see that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x) = F(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
hence I believe the function series converges for every $x\in \Bbb R$.

For the uniform convergence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|F_n(x)-F(x)\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|\to0$$
hence the function series converges uniformly.

I would be very happy for remarks, thanks.

Comment: The domain of $F_n(x)$ is $[0,\infty)$.  What happens to $F_n(x)$ when $x=0$?  Does that alert you to a problem of UC on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: yeah it mean im dividing by zero, not good

Comment: Note that $F_n(0)=\sqrt {n}\to \infty$.

Comment: This is not a power series, so "radius of convergence" is not what you want to say.

Comment: You should specify a domain for which you ask about uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$$F_n (n^{-1} ) =(\sqrt{2} -1-2^{-1})\sqrt{n} \to -\infty$$ therefore the sequence is not uniformly convergent even on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: do you think its okay to say that since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} $$so we can conclude that the series converge for $0<x<\infty$ but since it does not converge for $x=0$ we can say that it does not CU?